# Correlated subquery in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a query like below to find the stock details of certain products.The query is working fine but i think it is not efficient and fast enough(DB: postgresql version 11).

There is a CTE "result_set"in this code where i need to find the "quantity of a product ordered"(qty_last_7d_from_oos_date) during the period between out of stock and last 7 days before out of stock date.Same like this i have to find the revenue also.

So what i did is wrote a same subquery two times one outputting the revenue and other the quantity which is not an efficient step.So someone have any suggestions on how to rewrite this and make it an efficient code.

```
     WITH final as
    (
        SELECT  product_id,product_name,item_sku,out_of_stock_at
        ,out_of_stock_at - INTERVAL '7 days' as previous_7_days
        ,back_in_stock_at  
    FROM oos_base
    )
SELECT  product_id,product_name,item_sku,out_of_stock_at,previous_7_days
    ,back_in_stock_at

    ,(SELECT coalesce(sum(i.qty_ordered), 0) AS qty_last_7d_from_oos_date
          FROM ol.orders o
            LEFT JOIN ol.items i ON i.order_id = o.order_id
            LEFT JOIN ol.products p ON p.product_id = i.product_id AND i.store_id = p.store_id
          WHERE o.order_state_2 IN('complete','processing')
          AND f.product_id=p.product_id 
          AND o.created_at_order :: DATE BETWEEN f.previous_7_days::DATE AND COALESCE(f.out_of_stock_at::DATE,current_date)
    )
   ,( SELECT coalesce(sum(i.row_amount_minus_discount_order), 0) AS rev_last_7d_from_oos_date
          FROM ol.orders o
            LEFT JOIN ol.items i ON i.order_id = o.order_id
            LEFT JOIN ol.products p ON p.product_id = i.product_id AND i.store_id = p.store_id
          WHERE o.order_state_2 IN('complete','processing')
          AND f.product_id=p.product_id 
          AND o.created_at_order :: DATE BETWEEN f.previous_7_days::DATE AND COALESCE(f.out_of_stock_at::DATE,current_date)
    )
    FROM final f
```

In the above code the CTE "final" gives you two dates "out_of_stock_at" &
"previous_7_days". I want to find the quantity and revenue of a product based on this 2 dates means between "previous_7_days" & "out_of_stock_at".

Below query will give the quantity and revenue of the products but the period between   "previous_7_days" & "out_of_stock_at"from the above CTE.

As of now i have used the below code two times to obtain the information of revenue and quantity.

```
    SELECT coalesce(sum(i.qty_ordered), 0) AS qty , 
  coalesce(sum(i.row_amount_minus_discount_order), 0)
              FROM ol.orders o
                LEFT JOIN ol.items i ON i.order_id = o.order_id
                LEFT JOIN ol.products p ON p.product_id = i.product_id AND i.store_id = p.store_id
              WHERE o.order_state_2 IN('complete','processing')
              AND f.product_id=p.product_id 
              AND o.created_at_order :: DATE BETWEEN f.previous_7_days::DATE AND COALESCE(f.out_of_stock_at::DATE,current_date)
```

Comment: Please minimize and simplify your code to the most relevant parts!

Comment: S-Man edited the code and added some more information.Any suggestions please?

Comment: S-Man Do you have suggestions please?